# Remove duplicate entries from strings fetched from cursor: Android

Tags: android, android-cursor

I am using Cursor to get a string of data. I have a list of companies and the cursor displays the town name in it.

```
 Cursor cursorMain = mDbHelper.getMainBranch(primaryID);
 int countMain = cursorMain.getCount();
 String townNameMain = cursorMain.getString(cursorMain
                                .getColumnIndex("z3"));
 Log.d(townName,"town name");
```

This gives me a list of town names. Now what I want is to remove the duplicate entries from it and get the size of the same.

I don't want to change the way I query my cursor. Is there any way to remove the duplicate entries from townNameMain above?
Can anyone please help.

EDIT: I am using a loop to get the names of the town like,

```
        String loc = tempList.get(i).getTownName();
        Log.d(loc, "locattion");
```

I am getting the names as:

```
D/ABC
D/ABC
D/ABC
D/AAA
```

Here how can I check for the same strings and eliminate them. Please help as I can't figure it out.

Comment: just go for string comparison

Comment: Don't add duplicate entry in your list by comparing them.

Comment: that would be `.equals()`

Comment: The strings of data are quite large and so is the number of duplicate entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the strings into your arraylist and then add these value into a set. Set do not allow duplicate values.

Something like,

```
        ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
        List.add(loc); //assuming u r getting the strings in loc.
        Set<String> aSet = new HashSet<String>(List);
        List.clear();
        List.addAll(aSet);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this helped. I looped through each of the data in loc and then used a set to store the data. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Set or TreeSet to store our list.Set data structure do not allow redundant data